# Loading UIImageView into UITableViewCell Accessory View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an jpg image named `Check Mark.jpg` that I'm trying to load into the accessory view of a table view cell. This is what my code currently is:

```
cell.accessoryView = 
          [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Check Mark.jpg"]];
```

in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

When I do this, nothing displays in the table view cell. I have checked the name of the file, and have tried putting it in the folder containing the .xcodeproj file and the folder containing all the code files. Neither of these have worked. I also tried declaring the `UIImageView` and `UIImage` as strong properties and initializing them in the `init:` method. None of this works. I can display the detail disclosure button in the view, so I know the accessory view is there, but I can't seem to figure out how to display this simple image.

Do I have to somehow load the image into my project?

Comment: Did you try creating the instance of UIImageView and then assigning it a frame?

Comment: Yes I did. Same result: Nothing

Comment: Can jpg images be loaded? Because all the examples I've seen have .png's. I don't know if that's an issue

Comment: Yes, jpg images work fine. You should separate your code into two lines and log the image to make sure it's being created.

Comment: When I instantiate the ImageView and log imageView.image, I get null. I wrote: NSLog(@"%@", imageView.image);

Comment: Is there a specific way I should put the image in my project?

Comment: Does the picture have to be a specific size?

Comment: I put in a 48x48 jpg using your posted code, and that worked fine. When you use initWithImage, the image view will be the size of the image. If you want the image view to be a certain size, then use initWithFrame:, and then setImage:.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After setting the image up try to set the frame next.

Something like this:

```
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Check Mark.jpg"]];
[cell.accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
```

I think the accessoryView frame is set to 0.

Comment: Well from what my own experimentation has led to, all the png files I try work, while all the jpg's don't